# org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

Tags: android, android-studio

My code is work properly in **android 9** only, before updated Gradle file is work properly after updating Gradle is showing error
less than version

```
org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

Comment: some of your value with same key Manifest is same

Comment: I do not understand some value is repeated But it works properly in android 9 only less than 9 version is not work

Comment: post your build error

Comment: How did you solve the issue?

Comment: Gradle file unused  facebook library just removing this library implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Some of your Libraries have similar dependencies
specifically jetbrains library check this [Article](https://medium.com/@terrakok/how-to-fix-gradle-build-error-java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry-83d102038056)